# Bash dropping out of sudo in a script

Tags: bash, sudo

I need to execute an install script using sudo, but towards the end of the script, the script needs to drop out of sudo and continue as the regular user.

Example:

```
sudo ./install.sh
```

script runs and does what it needs to as root

```
su myscriptuser
service myscript start
```

Basically, the service myscript start needs to be run by the regular user, not by root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`su myscriptuser` starts another shell in the name of `myscriptuser` and waits until it exits. Then it proceeds to run `service myscript start` in the name of root again.

What you need instead of the last 2 commands is sudo:

```
sudo -u myscriptuser service myscript start
```